# d3.js / CoffeeScript: Access execution context (this) of both class and path in mouseover

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, d3.js

I'm using a [d3.js Streamgraph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060954) in a CoffeeScript class.  I've adapted it so that on mouseover the color of the path changes and a tooltip appears.

Now I want to pull out some of the tooltip logic into a separate function.

I can adjust the execution context to either one or the other, but can't figure out how to pass both:

```
class Graph

    render: ->
        ...
        dataArea.enter()
          .append("path")
              .on("mouseover", @onMouseOver)            # Option 1 - Pass path context
              .on("mouseover", @onMouseOver.bind(@))    # Option 2 - Pass class context

    onMouseOver: (data) ->
        d3.select(this).attr("class", "")   # 1.  Depends on path context (to adjust styling)
        @tooltipHelper(data)                # 2.  Depends on class context (which holds helper function)

    tooltipHelper: (data) ->
        ...
```

Previously I got some great help from @loganfsmyth on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443977/d3-js-coffeescript-class-execution-context) about click events.  This would suggest an answer along these lines:

```
.on("mouseover", (d) => @onMouseOver(d))

onMouseOver: (data) ->
  d3.select(data.target).attr("class", "")
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.  Hence another way of phrasing this question might be "what is the equivalent of event.target for mouse over events?"

Also relevant is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656680/d3js-mouseover-with-object-context-function-pointer) from @meetamit.  It suggests getting round this by assigning `this` (the instance of Graph) to a variable declared outside a closure, but I guess this isn't possible in CoffeeScript because this puts everything into closures.

Can you help?

Comment: You should be able to access the global variable `d3.event`, which should have all the information you need if I understand correctly.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff that's perfect.  It's `d3.event.currentTarget` that I was after.  If you put that as an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the global variable `d3.event` in these case to get access to all the information you need.